# How to pop alternate letters from a string in an encoding text program in Python

Tags: python

```
import random


def reverse(x):
    return x[::-1]


alphabets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
             'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
             'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

word = list(input("Enter text: "))
code = int(input("Type 1 to encode or 0 to decode: "))

if code == 1:
    if len(word) < 3:
        encoded_text = reverse(word)
        print(encoded_text)
    else:
        popped_letters = list(word.pop(0) for _ in range(0, len(word), 2))
        popped_letters = ''.join(popped_letters)
        remaining_letters = reverse(word)
        remaining_letters = ''.join(remaining_letters)
        print(popped_letters)
        print(remaining_letters)
        changed_string = remaining_letters + popped_letters
        random_letters1 = ''.join(random.choice(alphabets) for _ in range(3))
        random_letters2 = ''.join(random.choice(alphabets) for _ in range(3))
        encoded_text = random_letters1 + str(changed_string) + random_letters2
        print(encoded_text)


elif code == 0:
    if len(word) < 3:
        decoded_text = reverse(word)
        print(decoded_text)
    else:
        pass


else:
    print("Invalid input")
```

I want to pop alternate letters from the input and then reverse the order of remaining letters. But when I am providing input, for example: Hii I am Mark. The output I am getting in popped_letters is "Hii I a". It is popping letters in simple order, not alternately.

It would be really appreciated if someone can explain how and why this is happening. Thank you.

Comment: `''.join(l for i, l in enumerate(string) if i % 2)`…?

Comment: Did you write this code? There are some weird things here and there, like for example, popped_letters variable and other random variables and string management. If you want to return some words based on it's index, why dont you extract the indexes of the words and then return those word indexes?

Comment: @deceze It works but I have to use pop function. Only then the remaining_letters output will also come correct

Comment: @JoseM.González Yes, I have written this code. I have to use pop function only.

Comment: Who says you have to use the pop function? The obvious way doesn't.

Comment: What's the expected list for that example?

Comment: @KellyBundy I thought of using a different way but it is a exercise, in which it is given that pop function must be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pop() is going to return the popped letters, as long as you have:

```
word.pop(0)
```

in your for loop it will continue to return only the first element of the list. Since you're running a for loop, every time you run it the second element becomes the first one, so in the next iteration it returns the following letter for the whole duration of the loop.

so instead of:

```
popped_letters = list(word.pop(0) for _ in range(0, len(word), 2))
```

you need to do:

```
popped_letters = list(word.pop(x) for x in index_list)
```

Where x actually changes value as you iterate. But then you will have a second issue, that is that the size of you list changes with each iteration and your indexes will fall out of range, to make sure you can run this properly you could start popping letters from the end using something like this list:

```
index_list = list(range(0, len(word), 2))
index_list.reverse()
```

which will contain all the indexes to be removed starting by the last one. ([12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0])
Once you've popped all letters just reverse them again to get the right order:

```
popped_letters = list(word.pop(x) for x in index_list)
popped_letters.reverse()
popped_letters = ''.join(popped_letters)
```

which should return: "HiIa ak"

Comment: Thank you for explaining and providing your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

popped_letters = list(word.pop(0) for x in range(0, len(word), 2))  => Here you are always poping the 0 the element for (len(word)/2) + 1 times. For your example 'Hii I am Mark' has len =12, so poping first 7 letters i.e, 'H', 'i', 'i', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'a'. which is your output.
You can replace this by
popped_letters = list(word[x] for x in range(0, len(word), 2)) , to get alternate values. But here no poping is done.
Below is the changed code.

```
import random


def reverse(x):
    return x[::-1]


alphabets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
             'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
             'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

word = list(input("Enter text: "))
code = int(input("Type 1 to encode or 0 to decode: "))
print("Input:", word)
if code == 1:
    if len(word) < 3:
        encoded_text = reverse(word)
        print(encoded_text)
    else:
        popped_letters = list(word[x] for x in range(0, len(word), 2)) # No poping here
        print("popped_letters : ", popped_letters)
        popped_letters = ''.join(popped_letters)
        remaining_word = list(word[x] for x in range(1, len(word), 2)) # Used above logic, only change is index to find remaining value. 
        print("remaining_word : ", remaining_word)
        remaining_letters = reverse(remaining_word)
        remaining_letters = ''.join(remaining_letters)
        print("popped_letters joined: ", popped_letters)
        print("remaining_word joined: ",remaining_letters)
        changed_string = remaining_letters + popped_letters
        random_letters1 = ''.join(random.choice(alphabets) for _ in range(3))
        random_letters2 = ''.join(random.choice(alphabets) for _ in range(3))
        encoded_text = random_letters1 + str(changed_string) + random_letters2
        print("encoded text", encoded_text)


elif code == 0:
    if len(word) < 3:
        decoded_text = reverse(word)
        print(decoded_text)
    else:
        pass


else:
    print("Invalid input")
```

> Output

```
Enter text: Hi I am Mark
Type 1 to encode or 0 to decode: 1
Input: ['H', 'i', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'a', 'm', ' ', 'M', 'a', 'r', 'k']
popped_letters :  ['H', ' ', ' ', 'm', 'M', 'r']
remaining_word :  ['i', 'I', 'a', ' ', 'a', 'k']
popped_letters joined:  H  mMr
remaining_word joined:  ka aIi
encoded text tUYka aIiH  mMrcIq
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **must** use list.pop() then:

```
text = input('Enter text: ')

tl = list(text)

for i in range(1, len(tl)//2+1):
    tl.pop(i)

print(''.join(tl)[::-1])
```

**Console:**

```
Enter text: Hii I am Mark
ka aIiH
```